# How to do the backward of numpy.sctype2char. convert char to dtypes or sctype

Tags: python, numpy

[np.sctype2char(sctype)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/core/numerictypes.py#L1015)

this function will convert dtypes/sctype (such as 'np.float') to chars (such as 'd'). something like this

```
>>> np.sctype2char(np.float)
'd'
```

My question is, How to do the backword? convert chars such as 'd' to dtypes (such as 'np.float')? something like this (actually dose not exist)

```
>>> np.char2sctype('d')
np.float
```

I googled it, and searched inside the github though I didn't get what i want.

problem solved, a million thanks to w-m

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, your question is not clear. What does your linked code have to do with this question? Please explain more.

Comment: _"dtypes/sctype (such as 'np.float')"_ - `np.float` is not a dtype, it's just another name for the builtin `float`

Comment: @Eric please show me the code or doc from github to elaborate this, thx

Comment: Try `np.float is float` - it returns true

Comment: @Eric Got it! Thank u so much!

Comment: Note that `sctype2char(x)` is better spelt `dtype(x).char` in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `np.dtype` constructor:

```
>>> np.dtype(np.sctype2char(np.float))
dtype('float64')
```